# Codeigniter 3 MY_Controller no encontrado

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

El error es el siguiente, al extender la clase Register del MY_Controller para crear el logeo de usuario, me lanza el siguiente error. ¿Alguna idea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dice que no ha encontrado la clase, pero aun añadiéndola tampoco la encuentra.

**Controlador para el registro en .php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Register extends MY_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First name','trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last name','trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required|is_unique[users.username]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|valid_email|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|min_length[8]|max_length[20]|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_password','Confirm password','trim|matches[password]|required');

        //En caso de que no pueda registrarse correctamente lo redirecciona al index de nuevo
        if($this->form_validation->run()===FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->render('register/index_view');
        }
        else
        {
            $first_name = $this->input->post('first_name');
            $last_name = $this->input->post('last_name');
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

            $additional_data = array(
                'first_name' => $first_name,
                'last_name' => $last_name
            );

            $this->load->library('ion_auth');
            if($this->ion_auth->register($username,$password,$email,$additional_data))
            {
                $_SESSION['auth_message'] = 'The account has been created. You may now login.';
                $this->session->mark_as_flash('auth_message');
                redirect('user/login');
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['auth_message'] = $this->ion_auth->errors();
                $this->session->mark_as_flash('auth_message');
                redirect('register');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El controlador MY_Controller.php deberia estar ubicado en application/core/MY_Controller.php y extender la clase CI_Controller.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Adicionalmente en el archivo application/config/config.php deberias tener configurado el sufijo a hacer utilizado para las clases que extienden el core.

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

En la documentación de CodeIgniter se detalla como extender las clases base https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! funciona!